# When translating a text, do you use "we" or "i" or "you"?

Tags: translation

I'm translating a random text our teacher gave us in school, but I never know which subject I should use. For example, this is the first sentence of the text:

> 小学生や中学生のころは、友達とお小遣いの話をよくしました。

I have no idea if I should translate the second sentence with I, you or we: "In the times of primary and middle school, **I/we/you** talked with my friends about pocket money a lot."

"we" as in "it is talked about" even though there´s no passive form of a verb. "you" as in adressing the reader.

Plus, I'm translating it to a Slavic language (just in case anyone here is familiar with that).

thanks!

Comment: The use of "my friends" suggests the use of "I", but I don't know enough Japanese to tell if "my" comes from the sentence or if you chose to use that.

Answer (score 20):

Japanese pronouns tend to be inferred from context. Since there is no context here it is impossible to know whether it should be I, we or you.

In real life, either in conversation or in a book you would never have just this one sentence and so it would normally be pretty obvious which pronoun is appropriate from what was said before.

Without the context, and if it makes sense, you should assume 'I' by default.